# onScroll() wouldn't execute when the current position is lastitem of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am trying to make my `ListView` update when the scroll is at the bottom of the screen, I have almost made it work but there is still a slight issue with the scroll.

First of all here is my code to detect the lastItem of `ListView`,

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
                currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
                ttc = totalItemCount;
                  // check if the current item is last,
                    if (currentFirstVisibleItem+currentVisibleItemCount == ttc){
                        Log.e("ss","I am here");
                        if (totalTime == timeConsumed){
                            Log.e("Last","Last");
                            // add data on listView
                            // update listView
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }
                }
```

When I execute the app , I scroll all the way to the bottom so that `if (currentFirstVisibleItem+currentVisibleItemCount == ttc)` condition become true, and it working because i am getting a message on `Log.e` `I am here`.

At this point, I am already at the bottom of the screen and wait for
`if (totalTime == timeConsumed)` block to execute, which will execute after 5seconds. As soon as `if (totalTime == timeConsumed)` block is executed I get the Log message, `Log.e("Last","Last");` because I am already at the bottom of the `ListView`, but the problem is, `notifyDataSetChanged` is not executed automatically eventhough I am already on the bottom of `ListView`, and in order to execute `notifyDataSetChanged()` i have to touch the screen, only then it is executed.

Why `notifyDataSetChanged()` is not executed when `Log.e("Last","Last");` is executed ? even though I am already at the bottom of the screen ? Why I have to touch the screen to make `notifyDataSetChanged()` execute ?

Comment: Where are you changing the underlying data?

Comment: the data is changed in the same `if` block, i.e `if (totalTime == timeConsumed)`

Comment: So you're changing the data and notifying the change, there must be something up with the code to change the data so...

Comment: i know there is something up, but the problem is with the scroll instead of data because when i am scrolling up slightly and scrolling back down a little then `notifyDataSetChanged` is executed.

Comment: If your log is executed then `notifyDataSetChanged` is executed. That's a given. The issue must be that there's no changes to update when this is executed. You'll have to post more code.

Comment: hello, No, I have shown the time just for the sake of simplicity to explain what I am doing, and nothing else is causing the time to not elapse. I think this is how `onScroll`, one more thing i would like to mention that, I do not need to scroll up and scroll down again, as I mentioned earlier, I was wrong. I just have to touch the screen to cause `notifyDataSetChanged` to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered handling this functionality in your adapter? In `getView` you can check to see if the position is the last data item and kick off an async call to load another page of data.

Comment: Actually i do not want that....my code is working when I am scrolling manually but if the default position is bottom it doesn't execute. and what you have posted doesn't answer my question.